# Connect two docker instances in localhost with port exposed mappings

Tags: docker

I have two docker containers wanted to work as connected. One docker instance(**instance1**) is connected with the client and another docker(**instance2**) is wants to connect with instance1. Mainly what it does is when the client sends a request to instance 1, instatnce1 wants to invoke instance2 service and get the response. Then pass it to the client.

Currently, I'm using following docker commands to run the docker images

**instance1**

```
docker run --name instance1 -d -p 8290:8290 composite-service
```

This instance has a service  - http://localhost:8290/composite .
This service invokes the service in **instance2**

**instance2**

```
docker run --name instance2 -d -p 8291:8290 service-backend
```

This instance has a service  - http://localhost:8291/service. When this called service response some data to the request. (actually, this service is started on port 8290, but it exposes to externals in 8291 port)

The problem is when the client called to the service in **instance1** (http://localhost:8290/composite) it shows an error

```
Connection refused or failed for : localhost/127.0.0.1:8291
```

How can I resolve this? I want to connect these 2 containers with existing port mappings passed in the docker run commands.

I tried `--link` and `--net` commands to connect these two containers but the result was same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on bellackn’s Answer the easiest way in my opinion is with docker compose.

The dockercompose file would look something like this.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  service:
    image: composite-service:latest
    ports:
      - 8290:8290
  backend:
    image: service-backend:latest
    expose:
      - 8290
```

Now instead of using `docker run …` you save the code above in a file called `docker-compose.yml`, and run `docker-compose up` from the folder that file is saved in.

Now your composite-service no longer should call http://localhost:8291/service , but instead use something like backend:8290/service.

You can read more about compose-files in the official documentation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

An added benefit is that this way the `service-backend` is only accessible within the docker compose network (not on your local host).
If you want access to your backend remove the `expose` statement and add the `ports`.

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` inside a container always refers to the container *itself* (unless you start them with `--net host`).

If you want containers to communicate, I recommend [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/). The containers can then refer to each other using their service names (if you run them in the same network, of course, but that's the default), i.e. `instance1` could reach `instance2` via `http://instance2:8291/service`.

Comment: I tried ```--net host ``` command when running the docker image. But the problem is it not allowed to keep port mappings and it raised a warning saying it. Can you please help me to how to do it with **Docker Compose** or any other simple way to do this? As a simple solution, I tried to create a network and used `--net <network-name>``` command. But I failed

Comment: When using the host network, you can set the `-P` flag instead of `-p ...`. This way, any port you configured under `EXPOSE` in your Dockerfile will be mapped from your container to the "real" localhost. Try this for a quick check maybe. I will come back later for a more detailed answer on how to do this with Docker Compose.

Comment: When I use ```docker run --name instance1 -d --network="host" -P 8290:8290 composite-service``` command now its saying **Unable to find image '8290:8290' locally**. Do you know why is this?

Comment: Just drop the port numbers, `-P` is enough. Again, this depends on whether you defined the ports in your Dockerfile with `EXPOSE`.

Comment: Didn't work. Can you help me to do this with **Docker Composer** ?

Comment: Can't I do this with a custom created network? I meant ```--net <my-network> ```?